Pi 4 Kali 32-bit & 64-bit download corrupt and Sha256sum mismatched
I have tried downloading both the 32-bit and 64-bit images from the Kali Linux website. It produced the error of 'compress data corrupt ' after extracting the images, and Sha256sum also mismatched when comparing with the sum given in the Kali official website.
For instance, Raspberry Pi 2 (v.1.2), 3, 4, and 400 (64-bit), sha256sum as per the website:
79ed6967994a80a14b0d08021cb7a0ce6425c1dc0a4b876185bb0416b3dde893

When I checked at the terminal with the command as
sha256sum kali-linux-2024.2-raspberry-pi-arm64.img.xz 
f44ea39282f34b9bec3fc790e280194ad07164926bdd177d8d8bccb6f33e645c.

I also attempted a couple of times and had the same results. Any possible fix?

I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug report, not a question

You should flag this with the maintainers/publishers. Only they can give you a valid answer

Hello, Thanks.  It had officially fixed and updating their Sha256sum as 3eed2c9c2bbfcc4d02192af1b762428ae338ec7c67c77656108d4b738376f7ca.  It  is matching with the  ARM images  for my download.

@ArchurCl4w What should I do when someone answers my question?
